# How to get new tokens on Solana / Raydium

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

What I want to achieve: I would like to get all new swappable tokens on Raydium (Solana).

What I tried: I figured out that for Raydium I need the token it to look for, so I tried out to get all tokens, new tokens, whatever created in Solana but everything I found was getting tokens from a account giving an account id or similar things as parameters.

But I don't have any of these, because exactly this is what I'm looking for, these IDs from new tokens.

I tried to check out Solascan pro API but the authorization even failed in the test environment on the website itself (https://pro-api.solscan.io/pro-api-docs/v1.0)

I read the docs from the following websites: https://docs.solana.com/ https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/ (Python api version) https://solanacookbook.com/ and a few other websites and community posts but the only thing I got so far is nothing. What can I try next?

Comment: Hi. Did you find any proper documentation or solution to see newly created tokens in real time? I've been searching on Raydium GitHub docs as well and nothing so far.

Comment: Same here these suckers are not letting the code open source once I crack it I'm gonna write an article an open source it on my repo

Comment: Nope nothing guys, still lost in the Solana space

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the specific accounts and parse their instructions to detect the new pools. Use `logssubscribe` websocket method to subscribe to the incoming signatures. I've been able to successfully fetch new mints but lol no success on how to swap new tokens on `raydium`.

https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe

You can use `helius` or `quicknode` RPCs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'specific accounts'? You filter out by somehow detecting it comes from Raydium?

Comment: it would be nice to share a script :)